# Delete Files created by root?

Tags: ubuntu

I have an automatically generated docker container, which creates a build output. The files are created by the root user, e.g. /home/buildUser/bla/*.*

Now the buildUser cannot delete the files anymore, because they are owned by root and the buildUser has no admin rights.
How can I fix this? I would prefer a solution wich does not need a script to run everytime. Nor can I modify the docker container, since it needs root due to some thirdparty...

Comment: A user can still delete a file owned by root if he has write permission on the directory, though he will get a warning if he doesn't have write permission to the file itself and doesn't use `rm -f`. Provided that directories are not created dynamically, they can be set to have all-write permissions just once. Alternatively, you could write a custom version of `rm`, owned by `root` and with the `SETUID` bit set, but it would need to be a program: a script would be too easy to hack.

Comment: @AFH it's more annoying than I thaught. The folder /build is owned by builUser, but  the buiild process generates folders like /build/obj and then you buildUser cannot delete /buil/obj/somefile.txt anymore...

Comment: Does it recreate existing folders? If not, then you need to run once `sudo find /build -type d -exec chmod -v {} \;`. After that anyone will be able to delete files in `/build` and all of its subdirectories. Alternatively, if you want to restrict to certain users, you can modify the group settings of the directories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the container has root privileges, if it could create files owned by root. So why not use it to gain root again and delete them?

For example, you can use the `phusion/baseimage` image which is a Docker-optimized Ubuntu image. If you can't run arbitrary images, try to supply `bash` as a command to ones you have access to (just substitute `phusion/baseimage` for your image name).

```
gronostaj@ubuntu:~$ docker run -it --rm -v /home/gronostaj:/mnt:z phusion/baseimage bash
root@612d766be480:/# cd /mnt
root@612d766be480:/mnt# rm -rf unwanted_folder
```

Congratulations, you've just learned about dangers of misconfigured Docker.